# Is it possible to create an array of a String type and promote it to a double for computation?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create an array in Java that takes in a person's time-in and time-out and computes for total hours. Is it possible to do this with an array? And, if so, how do I promote a string (in this case time-in and time-out) into doubles to be computed?

Comment: Can you please add the code showing your current structure and attempt to implement that?

Comment: why wouldn't it be? why do you call a process like this "promoting" ?

Comment: this question is very vague, nobody can guess what is really your use case. Try to provide what you have. Personaly I would go with map (key being time-in and value being time-out) - but only in case this map would be owned by person object..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to compute the duration between given dates. I suggest using Java's [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class.

But first, you need to transform your strings into date objects, so that it can be calculated with Duration.

Example:

```java
String[] dates = new String[] {
  "2018-06-05 09:00:00",
  "2018-06-05 18:00:00"
};

var formatter = DateTimeFormat.ofPattern("yyyy-MM- HH:mm:ss");
var convertedTime = Arrays.stream(dates)
  .map(dateString -> LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());

var start = convertedTime.get(0);
var end = convertedTime.get(1);
var duration = Duration.between(start, end);

System.out.println(duration.toHours() + " hours has passed.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your String is something like
1.0,4.0
you can use string.split(",") and Double.parseDouble to get the individual doubles from you String and work with those. And yes, you can then add them to a new Array, but no, you can't change the type of an existing Array from String to double - there shouldn't be a need to do so.